# How do I not throw the stack trace during throttling exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, exception, stack-trace, throttling

How do I not throw the stack trace during throttling exceptions?

Comment: A that's something you'll need to take care of at the place you catch and log the exception. Or you could override `getStackTrace` on `ThrottlingException`.

Comment: @tgdavies Could you expand more (possibly with code) on how I could override getStackTrace on ThrottlingException? Thank you.